# How to sign-out Google from Sign-in Auth using alert view

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, google-signin

I have A right bar button item (using SWReveal Controller) and I want to logout using alert view showing "OK" and "Cancel" pop up  if I  click on "OK" it should signet and have to navigate to sign-in page and if I click on "Cancel" it should remains same .......

I am getting errors

here my code :

```
 @IBAction func logoutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you Sure You want to Logout", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        switch action.style{
        case .default:
            print("Please Enter Details")

        case .cancel:
            print("cancel")

        case .destructive:
            print("destructive")
        }}))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signinpage") as! ViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in
        switch action.style{
        case .default:
            print("Please Enter Details")
        case .cancel:
            print("cancel")

        case .destructive:
            print("destructive")
        }}))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     let secondViewController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")  as! HomeViewController
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController2,  animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description you need

```
@IBAction func logoutButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you Sure You want to Logout", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signinpage") as! ViewController
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([secondViewController], animated: true)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler:nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

When logging out it's better to use `setViewControllers` instead of `popViewController`  as the latter will leave old vcs in stack